# Is there a way to upload files to a project in such a way that it is possible to use their content in the code of the app?

Tags: android, serialization

I'm trying to copy some files into an AndroidStudio project in order to read their content while creating the main activity of my app. I tried to simply copy them in the folder with the Java classes and in this case, I can't access them programmatically. I tried to look for other solutions, but I didn't manage to find anything that solves my problem. Is there a way to do it?

(In particular, the files that I need to upload are obtained by serializing Java objects in Eclipse.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asset Folder

```
   try {
        InputStream fio = getAssets().open("students");
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fio));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = bis.readLine() )!=null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        Log.d("NAME",sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I create that folder? Sorry but I'm new to AndroidStudio

Comment: Double click on "app" folder choose "New" --> "Folder" -->"Asset folder"

Comment: I tried to include your line in AndroidStudio but the method `getInputStream()` is not recognised. I'm trying to modify my code             
`FileInputStream fis=this.openFileInput("filename");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);`
to use the assets but I'm stuck

Comment: Here is an example to read a text file

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do it in the meantime and you're giving me an additional confirmation that I did it correctly!

Comment: Glad i could help ^_^